# How to create a file name for each sub directory using Bash

Tags: bash

I have a folder structure like this:

```
.
+-- dir
|   +-- subdir1
|   +-- subdir2
|   +-- subdir3
|   +-- subdir4
```

And I want to create an `index.html` file inside each `subdir` using Bash:

```
.
+-- dir
|   +-- subdir1
|       +-- index.html
|   +-- subdir2
|       +-- index.html
|   +-- subdir3
|       +-- index.html
|   +-- subdir4
|       +-- index.html
```

I can list all of sub directories by using:

```
 .
 $ ls dir/*/
```

And create a file with `touch`, then I thought that the correct command would be:

```
.
$ touch dir/*/index.html
```

The result: `touch: cannot touch 'dir/*/index.html': No such file or directory`

How to create a file name for each sub directory using Bash?

Comment: You could loop over the subdirectories `for file in * ; do touch $file/index.html ; done`

Comment: @RichardHamilton, why is your answer deleted? Looks perfectly fine to me -- the only thing I might have changed is using `--` to fix functionality when a folder name starts with a dash.

Comment: @YMomb Nice comment! I would complete your solution with `for folder in */` because `in *` include the files directly inside `./dir/` folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Why `touch dir/*/index.html` doesn't work

Globs expand *only to things that actually exist*, or to the glob expression itself if no matches exist and shell options are all at default configuration. (It's possible to configure this scenario to result in no arguments being generated or in an error condition in bash, using `shopt -s nullglob` or `shopt -s failglob`).

Thus, if you have `dir/subdir1/index.html`, but `dir/subdir2/` with no `index.html` in it, `dir/*/index.html` will expand to only contain `dir/subdir1/index.html`, but not any reference at all to `subdir2`.

#### How to fix it

Glob to the things that exist -- the directories -- and tack on the things that don't yourself:

```
for d in dir/*/; do touch -- "$d/index.html"; done
```

The `--` is needed for the corner case where one of your directories has a name starting with a dash: You don't want `-dirname` to be treated as an option to `touch`; `--` indicates that all future arguments are treated as positional, preventing this circumstance.